# Merge returns NaN except for first row

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Hello I want to merge two dataframes which I load in in Excel. I convert the column which should be merged to "str". Suprsingly the code merges the first row but then returns NaN values....
The code I use is:

```
ListA=pd.read_excel(inpath,sheetname="Tabelle2")
ListA["Stücklistenkomponente"]=ListA["Material"].astype(np.str)
ListB=pd.read_excel(inpath,sheetname="Tabelle1")
ListB["Stücklistenkomponente"]=ListB["Material"].astype(np.str)
print(ListA.dtypes)
print(ListB.dtypes)
```

> Material                  object
>
> Material                  object

The shape of the two dataframes is:

**ListA**

```
Material
R 22B 2.0 7.72 11.0 Lo
X 127 1.5x4.64x4[G16.05.01] CL
L 431 2x6,96x5.5 Y
9999
L 431 2x5,96x5.5 p
F 631 2x6,96x5.5 a
N 431 2x6,96x5.5 v
J 431 2x6,96x5.5 
O 431 2x6,96x5.5 
VM 431 2x6,96x5.5 L
```

**ListB**

```
   Material                          InnerDiameter  OuterDiameter   Length  
    R 22B 2.0 7.72 11.0 Lo           2              6               8
    X 127 1.5x4.64x4[G16.05.01] CL   2              7               12
    L 431 2x6,96x5.5 Y               5              8               13
    9999                             0              0               0
    L 431 2x5,96x5.5 p               6              9               15
    F 631 2x6,96x5.5 a               8              5               26
    N 431 2x6,96x5.5 v               9              1               3    
    J 431 2x6,96x5.5                 12             6               89 
    O 431 2x6,96x5.5                 5              4               12  
    VM 431 2x6,96x5.5 L              4             12               7
```

**It returns:**

```
           Material       InnerDiameter    OuterDiameter  Lenth  
           R 22B 2.0 7.72 11.0 Lo    2                 6      8   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN   
                   NaN              NaN               NaN    NaN
```

So what am I doing wrong? I think the solution is to convert both columns to dtype string but this is not working....

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there has to be some different data, maybe traling witespaces, because `.astype(str)` correctly convert data to `string`s.

If in data are `string`s, `dict`s, `set`s, `list`s then `dtype` is `object`.

But `type` is `string`, `dict`...

You can check it by:

```
print(ListA["Stücklistenkomponente"].apply(type))
```

For check data better sometime help generate `lists`:

```
print(ListA["Stücklistenkomponente"].tolist())
print(ListB["Stücklistenkomponente"].tolist())
```

EDIT:

I test your data and result is really interesting:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('Mappe3.xlsx',sheetname="Tabelle2")
df2 = pd.read_excel('Mappe3.xlsx',sheetname="Tabelle1")

#default inner join - get duplicated rows, because duplicate values
#on should be omit if only one same column for join
df = pd.merge(df1, df2)
print (df.head(10))
                   Stücklistenkomponente Ritzel_Materialnummer  \
0  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
1  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
2  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
3  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
4  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
5  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
6  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
7  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
8  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
9  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
...
...
```

---

```
#remove duplicates in both df
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('Stücklistenkomponente')
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates('Stücklistenkomponente')

#default inner join - only 5 same categories
df = pd.merge(df1, df2)
print (df)
                   Stücklistenkomponente Ritzel_Materialnummer  \
0  RITZEL 22F 2.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.13   
1  RITZEL 22F 3.0 7.72 11.0 Z17 SCHWEISS           401.4425.15   
2       RITZEL 22F 3.0 7.9 6.0 Z17 PRESS           401.4425.11   
3       RITZEL 22F 3.0 6.0 15.0 PRESS Z8           401.4487.01   
4       RITZEL 22F 4.0 7.9 6.0 Z17 PRESS           401.4425.14   

  Innendurchmesser  Außendurchmesser  Länge         Material1 Material2  \
0                2              7.72   11.0           X46Cr13         -   
1                3              7.72   11.0           X46Cr13         -   
2                4              7.90    6.0  42CrMo4 vergütet         -   
3                3              6.00   15.0  42CrMo4 vergütet         -   
4                2              7.90    6.0  42CrMo4 vergütet         -   

  Material3  
0         -  
1         -  
2         -  
3         -  
4         -
```

Comment: Unfortunately the data are the same and also checking the dtypes does not reveal any differences.... no idea

Comment: Further, why does it work for the fist row but then stops

Comment: Data are same column wise? What return `print(ListA["Stücklistenkomponente"] == ListB["Stücklistenkomponente"])` ?

Comment: But it seems data related problem, is possible upload data to gdocs, dropbox or send me them to my email in my profile?

Comment: Have sent the data to your mail.

Comment: I answer - missing second file. Maybe forget.

Comment: The second file is in Tabelle2 of the excel map. So the map has the sheets 1 and 2

Comment: oops, I miss it.

Comment: There must be something wrong.... check the shape of the "duplicated removed" df and then test by hand and you would see that there are many more than 5 equal notations.... I have no idea why this is not working

Comment: Hmmm, it seems there are only 5 same values, do you think it is wrong? I  think there should be problem with clean keyword in df2, but after remove it still same output :(

Comment: Yeah because if I manually (using excel), drop the duplicates of each list it returns 102 and 96 unique values for the column "Stücklistenkomponente". If i further pick the values of df2 and search manually in df1 for those values, I will find each single value - often multiple times - thus, it is not valid that there are only 5 common values

Comment: Normally I would say thats not possible but doing a VLOOKUP using excel delivers the desired result....each value of df2 is merged to df1 (multiple times) as expected..... I have still absolutely no idea why this has not worked with pd.merge().... Havn't tryied to save the xlsx file as csv or as txt yet...

Comment: Indeed... if I run the VLOOKUP function of Excel it merges (ofcourse only the first occurence) the data of the two lists....

Comment: I am curious, do you solve your problem? What was problem?